# The webpage cannot be displayed in IE11?

Tags: html, iframe, internet-explorer-11

I have an iframe in a popup which loads fine in Firefox and Chrome and even in IE10 but when i check in IE11 it show "The webpage cannot be displayed" and the url becomes "res://ieframe.dll/unknownprotocol.htm#data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3Chtml...."

Already changed security settings and tested but didn't work.
Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Heres what a quick google seqrch for the URL turns up: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/receiving-resieframedllunknownprotocolhtm-error/f4782db8-fb43-42af-9023-7c6247073d98 - Please do that before asking.

Comment: already tried everything from google result but didnt work. :( .. My system is 64 bit and IE11 in win7.

Comment: Please post your `iframe` element's HTML.

Comment: The data are dynamic so below is just a portion of it.

Comment: The code is too long so here is the link to jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/38qqw5hg/  the html part is inside the json.

Comment: My bad, The code had dojo.IsIE and it does not work above IE10.

Comment: The code had dojo.isIE which is not recognized in-case the browser is IE11. So that part of code is neglected.
Code is working now when I replaced it with the following  code:

        var isAtLeastIE11 = !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) && !navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/));
                if (isAtLeastIE11 === true || dojo.isIE <= 10) {}